# How to navigate between the thumbnails in the photogallery from external link?

Tags: magento2

I want to change the active/current picture in the product photo gallery through an external action.

So trying to find the proper js to do it I've tried this:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
               $(window).load(function () {                             
                                      var $fotoramaDiv = $('#fotorama').fotorama();

                                        // 2. Get the API object.
                                        var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

                                        // 3. Inspect it in console.
                                        console.log(fotorama);

                                        fotorama.show(2);
                                  }                       
                        });
                    });
```

But keep saying TypeError: fotorama is undefined